# Can I ask to add a new result to a paper that has been accepted but not published yet?

Tags: publications

My paper got accepted for publication last week, and I have not received the galley proof yet. I recently learned that one of my results implies another interesting result, and I want to mention that in my publication. Deriving the new result takes no more than three lines, and I do not think it can be published on its own. Can I ask the editor to add a new result to an already accepted paper?

Comment: "I recently learned that one of my results implies another interesting result" did you learn from someone else?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I strongly suggest not doing that.

- If the correction will be accepted, it is a sign of "the editor is accepting non peer-reviewed results ---> paper is questionable", unless the editor is a proven expert in your field (and even then, it is obviously not a blind review and the editor has some interest in the accepted paper being finally published).
- if the correction will be submitted to peer-review, the paper will go back to peer review.

Comment: What do you strongly suggest not doing; not adding it, or not asking the editor? The first sentence makes it all very unclear.

Comment: "Can I add a new result to a paper that has been accepted but not published yet?"
I strongly suggest not doing that

Comment: Both reasons don't stand much. The first honestly and realistically is not a problem of the author, especially as he is going to publish there nevertheless. The second one just exists if the answer of the editor says so.

Comment: I've seen concluding statements variously labeled as [*Added in Proof*](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=%22added+in+proof%22) quite often in mathematics papers (example by my Ph.D. advisor is on bottom of p. 9 [here](http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/fm/fm101/fm10111.pdf)), but I don't know how common it is in recent years or in other fields. However, it will probably require a double-check by referees, which might be problematic if a publication delay could cause problems for the author(s).

Comment: @Alchimista I admit I am a bit rigid and asymptotic in the two points I present, however I think your comment goes exactly in the opposite directions and "not a problem of the author" is a moral shortcut, exactly as "a phd works 60h per week is not a problem of his supervisor" which in turn makes academia the black hole of empathy that it is nowadays, where median people *and also* the median professor *have to* work 50/60 hours a week because otherwise they cannot keep up with teaching duties, research interests and supervising students.

Comment: There is nothing unethical in a editor accepting a straightforward paragraph in proof. If the editor would say "yes we can, but there will be a new round of reviews", then OP can decide. I am simply saying so. I am saying that he can surely ask.

Comment: @Alchimista "There is nothing unethical in a editor accepting a straightforward paragraph in proof."
Since we are discussing about adding a new result to the paper, I don't see the reason why we make so much noise about peer review, then.

Comment: @EarlGrey because it seems that OP wants to point out a result that is *implicit* in the actual paper, and doing that takes no more than three lines. This is the Q! If OP would like to add new section, or change of different sort, I would have answered "it is up to you, but basically it would be treated as a new submission or at least the paper will go through a full round of review".

Comment: @Alchimista implicit does not mean trivial. This is a long shot for an editor (I repeat myself: unless the editor is a proven expert). Additionally, the question explicitly says "I recently learned" which leaves the door open even to discussing the authorship (did the author learned this at a conference? a co-author teached him/her?).

Comment: @EarlGrey you like to touch points that are just potentially related to the question.

Comment: @Alchimista you like to take shortcuts. Have a good academic life!

Comment: @EarlGrey the plus is for your wishes. I suggest that after your papers got accepted, you do the same proposal, although fictitious, that OP ask if he can do. And in case of a positive answer, then you retract the paper. This is the logic you have followed above.

Comment: @Alchimista If you are implying that I am too rigid in my "do's and don't do's", that my publications and my work did not got cited as much as they could and therefore I did not get a tenure track and/or a professorship ... hey, you may be right, I double down my wishes to you about enjoy academic life to the fullest!

Comment: @EarlGrey your resentment was implicit in your text, although not trivial and I did not mean so. But your comment about what one would retroactively deduce about the paper if the editor agree is curious indeed.

Comment: @Alchimista It is not the fact that it is 3 lines, or 3 paragraphs, or 3 pages: results are results, even if implicit, results have to go through peer review. Possibly blind peer review. For this reason I mentioned the working hours. If they are 41, or 45, or 55, or 65 instead of the canonical 40 hours/week, where do you put **your** moral threshold?
I resent the flexibility you are showing, which will make you successful in academia https://i.pinimg.com/originals/c6/12/ca/c612ca1172b567ce209f0960c3f92110.jpg

Answer (score 7):

You can certainly ask the editor. But, the most likely outcome is that the paper would need an additional review. I doubt that it would require starting the process over again, but the editor, unless they are already an expert in your subfield, would most likely ask advice of one or more of the original reviewers.

It would delay your paper's appearance, though perhaps not for long.

The alternative is to take the new results and incorporate it into some new paper with additional results, since you say it isn't enough to stand on its own. But others are fairly likely to notice the extension in the meantime, so you might get scooped on it.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you could certainly ask especially if implementing the new few lines is that quick and straightforward.
I would provide the actual addition in your enquiry letter, otherwise I suspect that the editor answer would be NOT by default. It must be something that s/he can evaluate on her/his own.